# javascript media player get imageframes

Tags: javascript, media-player, frame, video-player

I'm looking for an Media/Video Player Framework in javascript which can capture the imageframes of a video without playing it.

I already tried with html5 , but I can only capture some images of the video that are already played.

Does anyone have experience with a framework or knows one that gets a framearray of a video that wasn't played or where I can capture the frames of an unseen video?